# Multiple Views approach in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Similar to Windows Explorer, I have a list of folders as data, but I want to have multiple views, for ex: icon view, list view, etc.

This is my approach:

```
<Page.Resources>
   <DataTemplate x:Name="iconViewDataTemplate"> ... </DataTemplate>
   <DataTemplate x:Name="listViewDataTemplate> ... </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
   <StackPanel>
      <Grid>
         <Button x:Name="toggleViewButton" Content="Toggle View" Click="toggleViewButton_Click" />
      </Grid>
      <Grid>
         <GridView x:Name="folderView"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=folders}"
                   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource iconViewDataTemplate}"/>
         <ListView x:Name="listView"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=folders}"
                   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource listViewDataTemplate}"
                   IsEnabled="False"
                   Opacity="0"/>
      </Grid>
   </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

in the code behind

```
private void toggleViewButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   folderView.IsEnabled = folderView.IsEnabled ^ true;
   folderView.Opacity = folderView.Opacity ^ 1;
   listView.IsEnabled = listView.IsEnabled ^ true;
   listView.Opacity = listView.Opacity ^ 1;
}
```

1. Is this the right approach? I am concerned that if I have a lot of views, then toggling is not easy, because I have to track each view's state.
2. What is the best practice to implement this multiple views?
3. Can I have something like an interface for the view, then I can change the style:

for ex:

```
<IView x:Name="mainView"
       Style="{Binding istyle}"
       ItemsSource="{Binding Path=folders}"
       ItemTemplate="{Binding istyle.Template}" />
```

Then toggling can be done simply by changing the style in the istyle.

Comment: You could do this in a tab-view without a header. You'd get all the virtualization support and ease of use of a tab-view, and could control it using indexes tied to an enumeration or something.

Comment: I'd say the best way would be to use ViewModel first MVVM, and have separate ViewModels and use a ContentControl. But it's not a small task implementing MVVM half way through a project.

Comment: So does that mean each View (GridView or ListView) will be a separate View (with ViewModel) class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I picked is to use `<Frame>` where I can change the Frame with proper View I need.

```
<Grid>
  <StackPanel>
    <Grid>
      <Button x:Name="toggleViewButton" Content="Toggle View" Command="{Binding ToggleCommand}" />
    </Grid> 
    <Grid>
       <Frame x:Name="viewFrame"/>
    </Grid>
  </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Then in The ViewModel' ToggleCommand, I would make the Frame to navigate to new View.